# Create Hashtag in Facebook Dialog Box When Sharing Content

Tags: html, facebook, sharing

anyone know how to make sharing button on your website with default text in dialog box ?

Click Link below to see image and see the hashtag, i want to change it to be default when sharing my content : 
[Default Hashtag when sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzA1g.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is against the [Facebook TOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) to pre-fill the message field so even if you find a hack you will be violating the TOS.